# --defaults-group-suffix not working with correct credentials in .my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have problems connecting to my DB through `--defaults-groups-suffix`.

*~/.my.cnf*

```
[clientdblive]
user=xxx
password=xxx
database=xxx
host=mysql5.example.com
```

My bash script where I am connecting from:

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=dblive
```

Returns an error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

It somehow seems to ignore the host option in my config file. When connecting directly through the terminal with

```
mysql -h mysql5.example.com -u xxx xxx -p
```

it works fine :(

MySQL version:  5.6.19-67.0-log

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a special character (`#`) in the password. Putting the password in "quotes" fixed it.